# Can a Windows named pipe created in OVERLAPPED (async) mode be used for sync communications as well?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, winapi, overlapped-io

I have a Named pipe process that uses Async communication, it is created by calling [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, on the client process the pipe is opened using [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) with the same flag and connected with [`ConnectNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-connectnamedpipe).

My question is if I can use the same named pipe for synchronized communication too?
I am not sure since the documentation states that :

> If hNamedPipe was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, the lpOverlapped parameter must not be NULL. It must point to a valid OVERLAPPED structure. If hNamedPipe was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and lpOverlapped is NULL, the function can incorrectly report that the connect operation is [complete.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-connectnamedpipe#:%7E:text=If%20hNamedPipe%20was%20opened%20with%20FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED%2C%20the%20lpOverlapped%20parameter%20must%20not%20be%20NULL.%20It%20must%20point%20to%20a%20valid%20OVERLAPPED%20structure.%20If%20hNamedPipe%20was%20opened%20with%20FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED%20and%20lpOverlapped%20is%20NULL%2C%20the%20function%20can%20incorrectly%20report%20that%20the%20connect%20operation%20is%20complete.)

Does this mean the pipe must only be used for Async actions?

Thanks.

Comment: [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) turns an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.

Comment: synchronous I/O- this is asynchronous I/O + wait in place after I/O, if it return pending status, until complete. you can do this, but for what in this case use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag ? in ay way you of course need pass correct pointer to `OVERLAPPED` if you use asynchronous handle

Comment: @RbMm because the pipe being used is also used for async operations. Is the proper way to implement it is to have 2 handles, one for async  and the second for sync communication?

Comment: no, wrong way have 2 handles and you can not do this. correct way always use async I/O and not wait in place. but if very want -no problem and wait in place after some I/O until it completed